# Pycharm debugging does not work

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I have community edition version 5.0.2 of PyCharm. My Python version is 2.7.
The problem is simple.
In the 'Run' mode everything works fine. But when I try to insert breakpoints and launch 'debugging' mode, it does not stop at breakpoints. However, corresponding debugging window is appearing and buttons to "resume", "stop" and "pause" are there. But if I try to "stop" or "pause" it does not take any effect. Program works like it is in 'run' mode.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 56284 --file C:/Users/.../.../main.py
pydev debugger: process 8112 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 143.1184)
None
([], 75)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What could it be? In other Intellij products (such as Intellij Idea) I did not encounter such a strange issue.
Could anybody help?

Comment: are you doing remote debugging? no need pydev for local debugging. If you doing remote debugging, you must deploy your code first than start to debug. Can you describe your environment more clear to have better understanding?

Comment: Problem was solved. It was caused by cyrillic symbols in a path to the project: `C:\Users\Имя\PyCharmProjects\Project` Probably, it is a bug of PyCharm.